# Why does Ellaria Sand rule Dorne?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After Ellaria Sand stabbed Prince Doran Martell, she becomes the de facto ruler of Dorne.

If she is not of the royal bloodline, why is she allowed to rule?

Wouldn't one of Doran's relatives become the next ruler?

Comment: Who says she's `allowed to rule`? She just *does*. Also, the show's version of inheritance and succession are out the window, especially in Dorne.

Comment: @Mooz Well, if she *just does*, then she must have the backing of others to force her way. Is there anything from the books that hints at her having separate support from Doran and Oberon? (I know the books have not caught up to the TV series, but perhaps there are hints in there nonetheless.)

Comment: The thing with the books with this particular point is that Ellaria is supportive of Doran, and in the shows she stabs him, so we can't really cross over the info there unfortunately.

Comment: I guess the fact that suddenly Lady Olenna (and therefore the Tyrells/The Reach) are supporting Ellaria, so there's that

Comment: [Cus .....D&D](https://media.giphy.com/media/1014RBn4HVSTK/giphy.gif)

Comment: I hate how they assassinated Ellaria's character, turning her into some war-mongering hag. And it is so stupid. "Hurr durr, Oberyn was killed, how do we avenge him? By killing the rest of his family". Okay rant over, I need to go and take deep breaths now

Comment: May as well ask how Cersei now rules. TV logic. However, for an in-world explanation, there are many in Dorne who feel Doran is being too cautious. I would assume some of these people would have to have infiltrated the inner circle of Doran's elite guard and are on board with Dorne going to war.

Comment: This looks like the real life example of how Catherine became Empress of Russia. She pulled a coup against her own husband and then became Empress even though others also claimed the throne. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great It's just Russian elites thought she would make an effective ruler than other claimants and that her husband was considered weak.

Comment: The show basically glosses over other houses in Dorne, the factions in Dorne, sort of blends Sunspear with the Water Gardens with Dorne itself, ignores Dornish law, ignores that Doran also has an agenda and schemes and plots (even though they are the same thing), and blends Ellaria Sand with the Sand Snakes even though the Sand Snakes are not her children. As such, the detail of how or why Ellaria could pull off a coup and anyone would take her seriously as a ruler are just .... not there.

Answer (score 6):

Your question asks about both the show and the books (judging from your tags). In the books, however, Doran Martell is for the time being alive and well. He also has several children who are his direct heirs: Arianne, who is being groomed to succeed him (in Dorne, women have succession rights), Quentyn, and Trystane Martell. Ellaria Sand also apparently has no plans to kill Doran in the books, because Doran is not against taking action against the Lannisters (his inaction in taking revenge against them fueling her murder of him in the show).

In the show, Doran Martell only has one heir: Trystane Martell. Arianne and Quentyn do not appear. You're completely right that Trystane would succeed his father upon his death. However...

> Ellaria's daughters, the Sand Snakes, kill Trystane *as well*, wiping out House Martell.

Ellaria Sand then usurps the power in Dorne. She has no *legal* claim to the throne, but House Martell's army was apparently as displeased as Ellaria (and House Tyrell) was with Doran's inaction against House Lannister, as they just stand by and watch as Doran is murdered.

You ask how she becomes the "de facto" ruler of Dorne, but you also ask about succession and heirs. If Ellaria had any legal claim to the throne of Dorne, she would be the *de jure* ruler of Dorne. That is not the case. Becoming *de facto* ruler of anything does not require a legal claim, as we've seen several times in the series. Remember: "Power resides where men believe it resides. No more and no less." With the army and House Tyrell on her side, and no obvious legal claimants to the throne, Ellaria becomes the new ruler.

See also [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153421/how-does-ellaria-sand-and-the-sand-snakes-take-over-dorne?rq=1) for more thoughts on how they pulled it off in practice.

Comment: I love how in the show, they describe the houses to be centuries old, yet pretend that there are only two or three members alive of every great house. No Cadet dynasties, no younger lines, no distant relatives no sirrrrrrrr! The moment a couple of them sniff it, a great house is wiped out

Comment: @tobiasvl Doran Martell might be (still) alive in the books, but the books only go so far right now. He might be dead once the next book comes out.

Comment: @RichS Indeed he might, but if so, we don't know if or how Ellaria will take over the throne with three heirs in her way.

Comment: @RichS I added some details from the books about Ellaria and Doran's motivations in the books, which in my opinion makes it unlikely your question will become an issue in the books even if Doran dies.

Comment: “If Ellaria had any legal claim to the throne of Dorne, she would be the *de jure* ruler of Dorne. That is not the case. Becoming *de facto* ruler of anything does not require a legal claim” — just to make it explicit, “de facto” means “in fact”, and “de jure” “in law”, in High Valyrian.

Comment: This looks like the real life example of how Catherine became Empress of Russia. She pulled a coup against her own husband and then became Empress even though others also claimed the throne. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great Russian elites thought she would make an effective ruler than other claimants and that her husband was considered weak.

Comment: Oh poor Quentyn.

Comment: Buuut, doesn't Ellaria have children with Oberyn, making them the actual successor(s), once they come of age? As with Cercei and Tommen there is precedence for the mother ruling in her child's stead.

Comment: @user1129682 All the Sand Snakes, Ellaria and Oberyn's daughters, are bastards and therefore have no legal inheritance rights (including succession rights). Oberyn and Ellaria were not married.

Comment: @tobiasvl even in Dorne?

Comment: @user1129682 Fairly sure, but I can't find a source on it. Even if bastards have succession rights in Dorne, only the youngest Sand Snakes are Ellaria's daughters. The heir in that case, Obara, is the daughter of a whore (books) or peasant (show). She's also of age. Ellaria would not be involved at all in that succession.